# Interpretation of VAR and Granger causality

Tags: time-series, interpretation, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

Lead-lag relationships can be expressed by using a Vector Autoregressive model. There are countless papers in which the authors state that

> X showed a leading role over Y

(using the results obtained from a VAR).

However, sometimes Granger causality is used and it is said that

> X Granger causes Y

I know that it is not the exact same concept and that Granger causality seems to be stronger. But is there a more intuitive interpretation to differ the two? And is it common that the two statements above go hand in hand (X Granger causes Y <> X leads Y)?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, leading relations in VAR models are usually checked through Impulse-Response Functions (IRF). If this is correct, the fact that IRF's are computed using the VMA representation, while Granger-causality uses the coefficients of the actual reduced-form equations, might suggest that any equivalence might only hold for large samples [VMA representation result](http://pareto.uab.es/lgambetti/Lecture2M.pdf) [p. 10]. What I mean is that you should not expect to see in empirical works.

Comment: This paper appears to corroborate my comment: http://monde.cirano.qc.ca/~dufourj/Web_Site/Dufour_Tessier_1993_EL_ImpulseResponseAnalysis.pdf

Comment: I see, thank you for the useful links you provided! One additional question: When you have a reduced-form VAR, can you interpret the statistically significant coefficients on the lagged variables as "leading" the dependent variable?